# F# type inference of generic type arguments with numeric suffix?

Tags: f#

While playing around with map, apply and such to better understand them, the inferred generic types on the following code turned out not be what I expected, but the code still works:

Note: the // comments are written by me so I can show them, but they are the exact copy of the auto annotations printed by Ionide.

```
let map2 fOk fErr (a : Result<'a,'e>) (b : Result<'b,'e>)= // ('a -> 'b -> 'a0) -> ('e -> 'e -> 'e) -> Result<'a,'e> -> Result<'b,'e> -> Result<'a,'e>
    match a, b with
    | Ok aOk, Ok bOk -> fOk aOk bOk |> Ok
    | Error aErr, Error bErr -> fErr aErr bErr |> Error
    | Error aErr, _ -> Error aErr
    | _, Error bErr -> Error bErr


let lift2ResultFromMap2 f= // ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> (Result<'a,'d list> -> Result<'b,'d list> -> Result<'c,'d list>)
    map2 f List.append
```

Here I expected that the return type of `map2` is `Result<'a0,'e>` instead of `Result<'a,'e>`.
But then when I use it in defining `lift2ResultFromMap2` the return type is exactly what I expect, `Result<'c,'d list>` instead of `Result<'a,'d list>` that map2 would suggest.

Am I right to think this is an IDE bug? or is there some additional wildcard like meaning to the numbered suffix?

Comment: `a0` is not special - it's just a consequence of you constraining your input types, so the return type is calculated based on values it interacts with. If you loosen the constraints by using `(a : Result<_,'e>) (b : Result<_,'e>)`, you'll find that `fOk` becomes `'a -> 'b -> 'c`.

Comment: I see, so then the return type discrepancy is most likely just a bug. Especially if I remove all type constraints, then the return type becomes Result<'c,'d>. Note that while 'a0 changed to 'c for fOk, but for the return type 'a changed to 'c

Comment: It's not a bug really, let me write up an example.

Answer (score 1):

Your constraints are respected first. 
Now for your example, it tried to pick `'a` for the first unconstrained value, which is the return type of `fOk`, saw `'a` was already in use, so it went with `'a0`. So, if you let it pick the constraints with:

```
(a : Result<_,'e>) (b : Result<_,'e>)
```

`fOk` will be inferred to be `'a -> 'b -> 'c`. If you have enough values to infer up to `'e`, you'll end up seeing an `'e0`.

Comment: I get this, but what caused the initial confusion is that according to this, the inferred constraints just do not line up with what the function does. Depending on whether there is a collision with my user defined constraint, it infers that the whole `map2` functions last end Result's Ok will be the same type as the first argument of fOk, OR if there are no user defined constraints, it infers that the whole `map2` function's last end Result's Ok will be the same type as the result of fOk

Comment: Okay, that's likely a mistake on Ionide's part then. I'm in VS 2019, and it's fine for me.